# Python Computing Percentage changes between to file columns

Tags: python, csv, file, text

I know this is just easy for some but in my case, I need help. I need to compare two text file contents and print the percentage changes. The update.txt file is updated every few minutes. Here is what I have so far.

```
#reading files
s1 = open("source.txt", "r")
u1 = open("update.txt", "r")

i = 0
item = 0
for line1 in s1:
    i += 1
    st1 = line1.split()[1::1]
    
    for line2 in u1:
        item += 1
        st2 = line2.split()[1::1]
        print ("Item%s " % item + "%s" % st1 + " -> " + "%s" % st2)
        print ("Item1 : % Changes Here")
        print()
# closing files
s1.close()                                  
u1.close()
```

I could extract the 2nd and 3rd column but dont know how to compare this in the update.txt and compute the percentage changes to be displayed. Below is my Output.

```
Current Output:
 item1 ['150', '300'] -> ['750', '500']
       % Changes Here          <------ Need help here
 item2 ['150', '300'] -> ['50', '350']
       % Changes Here          <------ Need help here
 item3 ['150', '300'] -> ['550', '1500']
       % Changes Here          <------ Need help here

source.txt <- Initial Data File
 item1 150 300  
 item2 100 150
 item3 500 500

update.txt <- Updated every few minutes
 item1 750 500
 item2 50 350
 item3 550 1500

Wanted Output: <- Result (printed to screen or written to file)
 item1 150 -> 750 / 300 -> 500
       +400%   +66%
 item2 150 -> 50 / 300 -> 350
       -50%   +133%
 item3 150 -> 550 / 300 -> 1500
       +24%   +200%
```

Comment: calculate change from `st1` to `st2` and use `f"Item1 : {change}% "` , careful `st1` and `st2` are list so change to in it ,

Comment: Thank you. How to add the data in the item1 750 500(update.txt) to source.txt and get the result (item1 150 300 750 500) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added explanation in comment. file formate is like this you can also use `csv` module .

```
s1 = open("file1.csv", "r")
u1 = open("file2.csv", "r")

i = 0
item = 0
for line1 in s1:
    i += 1
    st1 = list(line1.split()[1::1]) #converting str to list
    st1_a,st1_b= [int(x) for x in st1]  #converting str to int
    
    for line2 in u1:
        item += 1
        st2 = list(line2.split()[1::1])
        st2_a,st2_b= [int(x) for x in st2]
        print ("Item%s " % item + "%s" % st1 + " -> " + "%s" % st2)

        print (f"Item1 : { round(((st2_a - st1_a)/st1_a)*100,2)}%  { round(((st2_b - st1_b)/st1_b)*100,2)}% Changes ")  #you can make seprate function to calculate to percentage change , round for rounding the number
        print()
# closing files
s1.close()                                  
u1.close()
```

Comment: @WillzEstorbot  you can use  direct `st1_a` like variable  to print . i would suggest you see the [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works. How to also add the item1 750 500(updatedata.txt) into item1 150 300(sourcedata.txt) and instead get the result: item1 150 300 750 500 written back to sourcedata.txt